# Get screen serial port in remote

Tags: gnu-screen, serial-port, telnet

I have some industrial equipment with serial ports equipped. There are 2 serial ports on each one (**COM1** `/dev/ttySC0` and **COM2** `/dev/ttyAMA0`).

Before sending to production, to test the correct functioning of the port, what I do is use the `screen` tool. So I open a `screen session` for `/dev/ttySC0` and `/dev/ttyAMA0`. Because I make a hardware bridge between both ports, when I type something in one session, the typed one appears in the other and the other way around.

So far all right. The problem is that now I have to do the same check on a remote ip-serial; that opens me ports 502 and 503, each for a serial port.

I tried to validate it by `telnet` but, although the communication with the ports is good, if I send something it is not received in the other (having a bridge between both).

I tried:
`telnet <remote-ipserial-ip> 502`
`telnet <remote-ipserial-ip> 503`

In each session, I add letters that should appear in the other session (I want that).

There is some way to use `screen` remotely? Any configuration for it by telnet?

Comment: Just use `cat /dev/ttyX` on your remote computer, where `X` is your serial-over-ip device. (Make sure you have read rights for that device.) Now just send your test string from your local machine. You should see some output from `cat` on the remote machine. It's not 100% synced but you may test a connection this way.

Comment: What if I haven't access to remote computer's shell? It`s not a computer as such, is a Ipserial with only a web service. @paladin

Comment: You could create a custom debug service which uses a command like that: `cat /dev/ttyX>>/var/www/mysite/debug/serial-test.txt` so you would be able to see the serial-output as a txt file hosted by your webserver. Make sure to delete the debug-output-txt file when you no longer need it.

Comment: dunno if there's a more eloquent way to directly call something like screen with default settings, but you can create a user and go into the shell's startup script (e.g. $USER/.bashrc)  and remove everything adding a line to screen followed by exit

Comment: if there's any way to specify a default com device in something like the .screenrc you could conceivably set the user account's shell directly to screen